# How to divide array into 3 object with certain conditions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have slice some word, into an array, and i want to divide that array into 3 object like this

input

```js
var input = "7RD FLOOR, PAVE AVENUE BUILDING, DUNG STREET, 48 JUNG-GU, SEOUL 100-203"
```

output that I want

```js
let addresses = {
  address1: 7RD FLOOR, ... (must < 35 char and word cannot be truncated)
  address2: BUILDING, DUNG STREET ... (must < 35 char and word cannot be truncated)
  address3: 48 JUNG-GU ..... (rest of array of input)
}
```

What I do, but it wont work

```js
let addresses = response.address.split(" ");
var i;
var counterDump = 1;
addressSplitDump['address'+counterDump] = [];

for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    if (addressSplitDump['address'+counterDump].join(' ').length <= 35) {
        addressSplitDump['address'+counterDump].push(addresses[0]);
        let sliceAddress = addresses.shift();
    } else if (counterDump == 3 ) {
        addressSplitDump['address'+counterDump] = addresses;
    } else {
        counterDump++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const input = "7RD FLOOR, PAVE AVENUE BUILDING, DUNG STREET, 48 JUNG-GU, SEOUL 100-203" 
const words = input.split(' ');
const address = {
    address1: '',
    address2: '',
    address3: ''
};

words.forEach(word => {
    if (address.address1.length + word.length < 35) 
        address.address1 += address.address1.length > 0 ? ` ${word}` : word;
    else if (address.address2.length + word.length < 35) 
        address.address2 += address.address2.length > 0 ? ` ${word}` : word;
    else 
        address.address3 += address.address3.length > 0 ? ` ${word}` : word;
});
```

Comment: OP wants `BUILDING` in second address, but your solution will give it in first.

Comment: @AZ_ that is just example, he want to have upto 35 characters and words should not be truncated. The only issue with Abito's answer is additional space at start.

Comment: @AZ_ In the question it is said that address.address1/2/3 should have a length less than 35 and words cannot be truncated. It is not mentioned that `BUILDING` should be in address2

Comment: @AbitoPrakash but the expected output does mention that, so I am confused if the explanation is wrong or the expected output. mostly the explanations are wrong.

Comment: Thanks @BilalSiddiqui. Edited the answer to fix the extra space issue

Answer (score 1):

Have a try on this

```js
let input = "7RD FLOOR, PAVE AVENUE BUILDING, DUNG STREET, 48 JUNG-GU, SEOUL 100-203 ADDED FOR TEST" 

let addresses = {
    address1: '',
    address2: '',
    address3: ''
};

const words = input.split(' ');
words.forEach(word => {
    if (addresses.address1.length + word.length <= 35) 
        addresses.address1 = [addresses.address1, word].filter(Boolean).join(' ');
    else if (addresses.address2.length + word.length <= 35) 
        addresses.address2 = [addresses.address2, word].filter(Boolean).join(' ');
    else 
        addresses.address3 = [addresses.address3, word].filter(Boolean).join(' ');
});

console.log(addresses)
```